# How to throw warning when creating a Custom Check-in Policy?

Tags: tfs

I have followed the following link, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668980.aspx to learn how to create Custom Check-in Policies on Tfs.

This worked great and I was able to create some policies. This policies only allow for a check-in to be done if they validate.

However now I am trying to develop policies that would only show a warning, and would allow the check-in to be done instead of obligating the user to validate the policies.

Does anyone has any idea of how to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to do this. It would not be a policy if it was not applied.

A policy is either active and required validated or removed and not. Users do get the ability to 'bypass' all policies.